# Jump to chunk(string) based on chunks(strings) count on specific page in PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I am new to iTextSharp. I have PDFS file in which I want to jump to a chunk(string) location based on the chunk(string) count. For example, in PDFS file I have around 100 chunks(strings) on page 5 and I want to jump to 53rd chunk(string) of the this page.

Please suggest how can I do this using iTextSharp.

Regards,
Manoj

Comment: What do you mean by "jump"? Are you talking about actually viewing the PDF, kind of like how searching "jumps" you are a PDF?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by *chunk(string)*?

Comment: Like, I want to collect all the string(word/chunks)into an string array and then loop throwh that array to locate the particular location of the string. So this would give me feature of jumping to a particular string(word/chunk) of data. Hope I was clear enough to make the question more sensible. For example, I would have a string array of 100 words and then from that I can locate or goto 53rd word. And then I can highlight that string in PDF.

Comment: Have a look at the source of [LocationTextExtractionStrategy.cs](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/LocationTextExtractionStrategy.cs); it collects text chunks as they appear in the content stream and collects them with their respective position. You might want to copy it and make the chunks publicly available to inspect. Using the chunk coordinates you can create highlighting annotations.